# Localhost port closed on Mac (Chrome) - need to get it working

Tags: localhost, port, local, development-environment

I am new to development on a local environment. I have setup my local env to run on localhost:8888.

Last night, my computer died when it ran out of battery -- I don't think this had anything to do with my problem, but just to provide background information. When I booted my local env back up, I get the following error:

```
This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I ran a port scan on the Network Utility app and my localhost is not up.

```
Port Scan has started…

Port Scanning host: 0.0.0.0

     Open TCP Port:     5432        postgresql
     Open TCP Port:     6001
Port Scan has completed…
```

What can I do to get it back up and running? This is on Chrome with a Mac running OSX 10.14.4.

Firewalls are currently down, so that isn't an issue, and I am able to access all other websites.

Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to develop a web application or a website, if yes maybe you just need to **restart your local web server**, which is necessary to test the web thing.

Then the webpage is available again in your localhost, just check in the configuration file to know which is the correct port.